# Quadratic approximation of $\frac{sin(x)}x$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, approximation

> Write down the quadratic $f(0)+f'(0)\Delta x+\frac12f''(0)(\Delta x)^2$ for $f(x)=\frac{sin(x)}x$.

$f(0)$, $f'(0)$ and $f''(0)$ are not defined. How could we produce a quadratic approximation at $x=0$?

Comment: You can use limits

Comment: Since $\sin$ is $C^\infty$ :  $\sin(x) = \sin(0)+ \sin'(0)x +\frac{\sin''(0)}{2!} x^2+ \frac{\sin'''(0)}{3!} x^3+\mathcal{O}(x^4)= x- \frac{x^3}{6}+ \mathcal{O}(x^4)$ so that $\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1- \frac{x^2}{6}+\mathcal{O}(x^3)$.

Comment: @user1952009 Just because $\sin$ is $\mathcal C^\infty$ doesn't imply that it equals its own Taylor series. Consider e.g. $1-e^{-x^2}$; other than that the idea is of course correct.

Comment: @Hyperplane Read again I didn't write any series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking about the correctness of the question, rather than the expected answer.

You are absolutely right to wonder about this. $f(x)$ is not defined at $x=0$, so what can $f(0), f'(0), f''(0)$ mean? The question is badly posed.

But in truth it is obvious what the question intends: it is about the function $f$ defined by

$$  f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x = 0$} \\
\dfrac{\sin x}{x}, & \text{if $x \ne 0$}
\end{cases}
$$

And this function is infinitely differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Well, when $\frac{g(x)}{h(x)} $ is analytic it is implicit its value at $a, g(a) = 0$ is $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$

Comment: What do you mean by "infinitely differentiable"? Are you trying to say "definitely differentiable"?

Comment: @W.Zhu: $f$ is infinitely differentiable if it is $n$ times differentiable for all positive integers $n$. See for example [this link](http://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Infinitely_differentiable_function).

Answer (score 1):

If you call

$$
f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}
$$

Use the limit

\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) &=& 1 \\
\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x) &=& 0 \\
\lim_{x \to 0} f''(x) &=& -1/3 \\
\end{eqnarray}

So that you have

$$
f(x) = 1 - x^2/6 + O(x^3)
$$

Answer (score 1):

You could recall that

$$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

which is the famous expansion for $\sin(x)$.  Then simply divide both sides by $x$.